# can't run my server because of mysql errors

Tags: python, mysql, django, server, runtime-error

I am doing a project in django and when i run my server python manage.py runserver i get the following errors.

```
Performing system checks...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x1045406a8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/bakeinsta/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/bakeinsta/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 194, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/bakeinsta/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 236, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/bakeinsta/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 86, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/bakeinsta/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 204, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61)")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/bakeinsta/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/bakeinsta/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 120, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/bakeinsta/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/bakeinsta/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 351, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/bakeinsta/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 73, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/bakeinsta/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/model_checks.py", line 27, in check_all_models
    errors.extend(model.check(**kwargs))
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/bakeinsta/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1200, in check
    errors.extend(cls._check_fields(**kwargs))
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/bakeinsta/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1272, in _check_fields
    errors.extend(field.check(**kwargs))
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/bakeinsta/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 894, in check
    errors = super().check(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/bakeinsta/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 206, in check
    errors.extend(self._check_backend_specific_checks(**kwargs))
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/bakeinsta/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 303, in _check_backend_specific_checks
    return connections[db].validation.check_field(self, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/bakeinsta/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/validation.py", line 21, in check_field
    field_type = field.db_type(self.connection)
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/bakeinsta/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 648, in db_type
    return connection.data_types[self.get_internal_type()] % data
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/bakeinsta/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 36, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/bakeinsta/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 133, in data_types
    if self.features.supports_microsecond_precision:
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/bakeinsta/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 36, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/bakeinsta/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/features.py", line 65, in supports_microsecond_precision
    return self.connection.mysql_version >= (5, 6, 4)
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/bakeinsta/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 36, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/bakeinsta/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 345, in mysql_version
    with self.temporary_connection() as cursor:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 81, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/bakeinsta/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 576, in temporary_connection
    cursor = self.cursor()
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/bakeinsta/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 255, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/bakeinsta/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 232, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/bakeinsta/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/bakeinsta/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/bakeinsta/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/bakeinsta/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 194, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/bakeinsta/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 236, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/bakeinsta/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 86, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/bakeinsta/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 204, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61)")
```

Comment: Check if a MySQL server is indeed running on your localhost.

Comment: Can you connect from the command line with `mysql -u username -p dbname` using your username and dbname from the Django settings?